# Wordpress query_post with variable category

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put my blog content into bootstrap tabs, where each tab is a category so it is kind of a filter.

Everything is working smoothly but I can't separate dynamically the categories posts on the tabs.

Here is my first code, where I make the tabs getting the current categories: (all good here)

```
<ul id="catstab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked cat_list">
 <?php  $categories = get_categories(); {
    foreach($categories as $category){                  
    echo "<li><a href='#" . $category->slug . "' data-toggle='tab'>" . $category->name . "</a></li>";
    } // end foreach 
    }
  ?>                    
</ul>
```

Then I make the containers for each tab with a loop inside each one: (all good here too)

```
<div id="cattabscontent" class="tab-content">
  <?php foreach (get_categories(array('hide_empty'=>false)) as $category)
    {
      echo '<div class="tab-pane fade" id="' . $category->slug . '">';
      echo get_template_part("loop");
      echo '</div>';
   } ?>     

</div>
```

Finally this is the query_post from my loop, and this is where I have the problem, what I need here is to give the category variable ($current_cat) the value of the current category, so it will get the correct posts on every tab.

```
  <?php query_posts(array(
    'category_name' => '$current_cat',
  ));
?> 
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
. . .
```

I have thought to give the variable the value of the ID of his parent, but I think it is not possible using only PHP, and I have no idea of how to make it using AJAX or something like that.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use single quotes around variable names, use double quotes. Single quotes will be interpreted literally not expanded to the value of the variable, so `echo '$var';` will give you `$var` exactly. Your code should either use double quotes or no quotes when setting the `category_name` argument, assuming that `$current_cat` is equal to the name you want to query on.

**double quotes**

```
'category_name' => "$current_cat",
```

**no quotes**

```
'category_name' => $current_cat,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `category__in` parameter like this:

```
  <?php query_posts(array(
    'category__in' => '$current_cat_id',
  ));
?> 
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Parameter `category__in` display posts that have **only this category and not children** of that category. You will have to use category ID in this case.

Parameter you are using `category_name` on the other hand displays posts that have **this category and any children** of that category.